# Lambda val with generic type in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Say I've got this Kotlin `typealias`:

```
typealias Checker<T> = (T) -> Unit

fun <T> checkNothing(input: T) = Unit
fun <T> checkSomething(input: T) = makeSomeAssertion(input)

fun <T> doSomethingWithAChecker(checker: Checker<t>) { /* ... */ }
```

Now I can call `doSomethingWithAChecker(::checkNothing)` or `doSomethingWithAChecker(::checkSomething)`, which is fine, but I'd rather define `val`'s with lambdas and the proper type alias so there's only ever one instance:

```
val checkNothing: Checker<T> = { Unit }
val checkSomething: Checker<T> = { makeSomeAssertion(it) }
```

But of course since they're instantiated they can't have that generic `T`, so I either have to define a type, or I can't pass them into `doSomethingWithAChecker`.

Is this possible without type casts?

Comment: What do you mean by, "I'd rather define val's with lambdas and the proper type alias so there's only ever one instance"? Do you want to avoid using the `::checkSomething` reference more than once?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the ::checkSomething as a default parameter to a generic function (i.e. doSomethingWithAChecker in the question). So I think it'll unnecessarily instantiate the checker every time, even though only one is needed.

Comment: AFAIK I don't think using `::someFunctuon` has any significant performance impact or cause multiple references. Why do you want to avoid using `::checkSomething` multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

The `val` declarations can be wrapped into a generic class which would supply the types of the checkers.

```
class Checkers<T> {
    val checkNothing: Checker<T> = { Unit }
    val checkSomething: Checker<T> = { makeSomeAssertion(it) }
}
```

Comment: Ah nice, this accomplishes the first goal of the proper type, but not the second goal of re-using checkNothing for checking different parametrized types (since it doesn't do anything anyway).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Any` type here to accept anything:

```
val checkNothing: Checker<Any> = { Unit }
checkNothing(123)
checkNothing("abc")
val checkSomething: Checker<Any> = { makeSomeAssertion(it) }
checkSomething(123)
checkSomething("abc")
```

Since your checkers here are consumers, it may be more correct to use `<in Any>` rather than just `<Any>`; more details on that can be read up on in the [generics reference documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)

Comment: Using a star projection may be better than using `Any`

Comment: AFAICT this would still require a cast when passing into the `doSomethingWithChecker` method I've got in the question.